# Fetch only one item from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to fetch only a single item from mysql database.This is my code
`<?php
$result=mysqli_query($con, "select`name`from users where name='ddd'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
print_r($row);
?>`

But it still gives something like an array
`Array ( [0] => ddd [name] => ddd )`

But I only want `ddd` to be displayed.

Comment: use `limit 0,1` for get one record. if u need use `asc` and desc` orders as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please get this

```
$result=mysqli_query($con, "select name from users where name='ddd'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
print_r($row[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch result from a query, it always returns an array.

Refer to  [PHP Manual mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

> **mixed mysqli_fetch_row** ( mysqli_result $result )
>
> Fetches one row of data from the result set and returns it as an enumerated array, where each column is stored in an array offset starting from 0 (zero).
>
> Each subsequent call to this function will return the next row within the result set, or NULL if there are no more rows.

To print the ddd field, mention this:

```
echo $row['ddd'];
```